# How do I pick position of tictactoe field by number input (0-8)?

Tags: python, numpy, tic-tac-toe

So I'm trying to refine my high school project by trying to restart at making a Tic-Tac-Toe Neural Network. However I can't wrap my head around how to set a cross or a circle at a position in the tic-tac-toe field by inputting 0-8:

```
class main():
    FIELD = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)

    def set(f, pos, type):
        #Line of code, where f is the field array, pos is a number between 0-8 and type is either 1 or -1 
        #(cross or circle) where f looks like this:
        #[0,1,2]
        #[3,4,5]    
        #[6,7,8] 
        return f

    set(FIELD,2,1)
    print(FIELD)
    #Expected Output:
    #[0,0,1]
    #[0,0,0]    
    #[0,0,0]
```

Thank you for any answersè :)

So I tried the following line of code:

```
f[(0 if pos == (0 or 1 or 2) else (1 if pos == (3 or 4 or 5) else (2 if pos == (6 or 7 or 8)))),pos%3] = type
```

But I think this is rather inefficient and I'm certain there has to be a way without hard-coding this lmao

Comment: Note that `pos == (0 or 1 or 2)` is not doing what you think. `(0 or 1 or 2)` evaluates to `1` as `0` is falsy and `1` truthy. You would need `pos in {0, 1, 2}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
FIELD = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)

position = 5
FIELD[np.unravel_index(position, FIELD.shape)] = 1

print(FIELD)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of set() should work.

```
def set(f, pos, type):
    row = pos // 3  # Calculate the row index
    col = type % 3  # Calculate the column index
    f[row][col] = 1
    return f
```